# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException with SSL and Postman

Tags: java, ssl, tcp, netty, vert.x

I have a complete minimum working example of a vertx server that will throw a `ClosedChannelException` if a request is made to it via Postman. From the point of view of postman, the request doesn't appear to have failed- the response is received as expected. It's only the vertx server that is throwing this error.

It is only happening once per new connection. Consecutive calls through postman won't trigger this error, but quitting postman entirely and making a call again will. It also will only happen if SSL is used. If the lines that enable ssl are removed, this error is not thrown.

If a request is made by a method other than postman (browser/fetch), no exception is thrown. Because I can only reproduce with Postman I might not be bothered by this, but I am seeing this same error appear multiple times per second in my non-local dev environment on AWS. I don't know for sure what the source of those requests are because the exception doesn't contain that information, but my assumption is that those are elasticbeanstalk health checks.

Sample-

```
package com.acme.server;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.*;
import io.vertx.core.net.*;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Configure Vertx

        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        // Configure HttpServer

        HttpServerOptions httpServerOptions = new HttpServerOptions();

        SelfSignedCertificate selfSignedCertificate = SelfSignedCertificate.create();

        // Comment out these lines and try `http` request. No exceptions thrown
        httpServerOptions.setKeyCertOptions(selfSignedCertificate.keyCertOptions());
        httpServerOptions.setSsl(true);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        httpServerOptions.setPort(4443);

        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer(httpServerOptions);

        // Configure Router

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route("/*").handler(routingContext -> {
            System.out.println("Requested route " + routingContext.normalisedPath());

            routingContext.response()
                    .setStatusCode(204)
                    .end();
        });
        httpServer.requestHandler(router);

        // Deploy Verticle

        vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle());

        // Listen for java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

        httpServer.exceptionHandler((exception) -> {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        });

        // Start server

        System.out.println("Listening...");

        httpServer.listen();
    }

}

class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
        startFuture.complete();
    }

}
```

Sample output-

> Listening...
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source)
>   Requested route /dddd
>   Requested route /dddd
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source)
>   Requested route /dddd

Comment: Which version of Vert.x do you use(share project dependencies and versions), please share more information, this issue could be related to the SSL handshake,  to be sure I need to know what versions do you use.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of any session information postman caches. Once you close the postman, may be the connection is closed by vertex, once you restart postman the request goes with some cached header values? Those session information will be not valid for your server. So server starts fresh connection and response is OK. 
Disable the caching settings of postman and then it might not occur.